# problema haciendo con session de express

Tags: javascript, express

estoy haciendo un curso y tengo un ejercicio que dice lo siguiente:

"En este ejercicio tenemos un controlador y nosotros debemos hacer que valide que haya seteada una variable en Session. Si esta variable se encuentra, se debe ejecutar el código normalmente, pero si no, se debe redireccionar hacia la página de login.

```
Para esto vamos a crear un if que consulte si existe el atributo admin dentro de session. Si es así, ejecutamos el código normalmente.

Este if que agreguemos tiene que tener un else en donde hagamos la redirección."
```

tengo este codigo pero no funciona, no se si alguien me pueda ayudar.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: "frase secreta"}));

const admin = (req, res) => {
    session:  if(req.session.admin !== null){(req,res) =>{
        res.send('hola');} 
        }
        else { 
             res.redirect("/login");
            }
     

    }
```

Comment: Cuando dices: "No funciona" a qué te refieres? Te da errores de compilación? Te da algún mensaje de error? Se te cierra nodejs? Cuál es el error, si hay?

Comment: te estaria faltando el return en el else **return res.redirect**